# Shared Memory segment : how to resize it?

Tags: c, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I'm currently implementing a coupling between two codes and to allow a communication between them, I have created a shared memory segment which is synchronized by named semaphores.

My problem is the following : I have created the shared memory segment with a certain size in the first process (using *shmget* and after *shmat*). Afterwards, I opened this shared segment in the second process (using *shmat*) and I have tried to increase the size of the shared memory. To perform that, I have used *mremap* with the MREMAP_MAYMOVE flag. If my understanding of the manpage is correct, this functions permits to copy the initial shared memory segment to its new localization and to increase or shrink the segment's size.

After this call to * mremap*, I have tried to access the new part of the shared memory and I got strangely a seg fault... I read that a solution to my problem would be to create a new larger shared memory segment, to copy the previous one in the second and finally delete the first one but I would like to avoid that solution.

Here below is the interesting part of the code :

```
  size_t old_size = (sizeof(coupling_strC) + sizeof(double)*4*npt_bnd);
  size_t new_size = (sizeof(coupling_strC) + sizeof(double)*4*npt_bnd + sizeof(int)*2*n_part + sizeof(double)*n_part);
  shm_addr = mremap(shm_addr, old_size, new_size, MREMAP_MAYMOVE);
  if(shm_addr == MAP_FAILED){
   perror("mremap");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  strC = (coupling_strC *) shm_addr;
  strC->pos_bnd = (double*) ( (size_t)shm_addr + sizeof(coupling_strC) );
        strC->vel_bnd = (double*) ( (size_t)shm_addr + sizeof(coupling_strC) + sizeof(double)*2*npt_bnd);
  strC->ind_part = (int*) ( (size_t)shm_addr + sizeof(coupling_strC) +  sizeof(double)*4*npt_bnd);
  strC->vort_part = (double*) ( (size_t)shm_addr + sizeof(coupling_strC) + sizeof(double)*4*npt_bnd + sizeof(int)*2*n_part);


  /*Writing of index of particules into the structure */
  n_part = 0;
  for(int i=0;i<sizeX;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<sizeY;j++){
      x_part[0] = (i+0.5)*h_part;
      x_part[1] = (j+0.5)*h_part;

      corners[0][0] = x_part[0] + 0.5*h_part;
      corners[0][1] = x_part[1] - 0.5*h_part;

      corners[1][0] = x_part[0] + 0.5*h_part;
      corners[1][1] = x_part[1] + 0.5*h_part;

      corners[2][0] = x_part[0] - 0.5*h_part;
      corners[2][1] = x_part[1] + 0.5*h_part;

      corners[3][0] = x_part[0] - 0.5*h_part;
      corners[3][1] = x_part[1] - 0.5*h_part;

      int check = 0;
      for(int k=0;  k<4 ; k++){
        if( ((((bbox_min[0]<=corners[k][0]) && (corners[k][0])<=bbox_max[0])) && ((bbox_min[1]<=corners[k][1]) && (corners[k][1]<=bbox_max[1])))){
          check++;
        }
      }
      if(check == 4){
        strC->ind_part[2*n_part] = i;
        strC->ind_part[2*n_part + 1] = j;
        strC->vort_part[n_part] = 0.0;
        n_part++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: So the mremap succeeded? And then you got a segfault, but _where_? If you have a core dump, it will show you the exact line and instruction that faulted. Are all the arrays you address in the loops after the mremap supposed to be in the shared memory? Are they still pointing to the old location?

Comment: Can you create a *minimal* runnable example that reproduces your issue?

Comment: Yes exactly, the *mremap* succeeded. And the seg fault occurred at the line :
strC->ind_part[2*n_part] = I; with n_part = 1. Therefore, at the first trial to access to the *new part* of the shared memory segment.
According to me, those tables are not pointing to the old locations but to the new one as I changed the reference just after the *mremap*.

Comment: Can you share the values of `i`, `j` and `n_part` at the moment of the segfault? Maybe the condition of `check == 4` is occurring more times than expected and you could be overflowing the allocated memory segment if  `n_part` is sufficiently large.

Comment: sorry, I just read the above comment stating that `n_part` was 1, please dismiss my previous comment

Comment: Why are you using System V shared memory, and not [POSIX shared memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html)?

Comment: One interesting thing to notice, I think that it was actually at the second attempt you accessed the memory you got your segfault, since `n_part` is initialized as 0 and is only incremented after you access your buffers for the first time.

Comment: @BlueStrat : you are right. Actually, I did a mistake in one of my comment. The segment fault is occurring at line *strC->vort_part[n_part] = 0.0* with *n_part = 0.*
And when I comment line *strC->ind_part[2*n_part] = i;* and *strC->ind_part[2*n_part + 1] = j;*, the set fault occurs at line *strC->ind_part[2*n_part] = I;* with *n_part =223*.

Comment: @Nominal Animal : just because I learned to use *shmget* and * shmat* at university and not *shm_open*, but I could use it instead for sure.

Comment: @PhilippeBilluart: If you did use POSIX shared memory, you'd need to use `ftruncate(fd, new_size)` on the underlying file descriptor first (to grow it to the needed size), preferably also using `posix_fallocate(fd, 0, new_size)` to ensure the shared memory is properly reserved, and then call `mremap(old_addr, old_size, new_size, MREMAP_MAYMOVE)`. This is commonly used for this.

Comment: When computing the addresses of the different regions in your resized buffer, If you change the cast applied to `shm_addr` from `(size_t)` to `(char *)` do you experience the same results? I know it is very unlikely, but perhaps under your running architecture the cast is invalid.

Comment: Throwing another idea, does your running architecture have any constraints on data alignment? (e.g. on ARM an integer must be aligned to a 4-byte boundary). If that's the case, could it be that the size of `coupling_strC` produces an unaligned address for `strC->indpart`?